# MSYS2 based gcc in Windows 10 does not output to standard msys2 console

Tags: c, msys2

I installed gcc in my linux VM and in Windows 10 host through MSYS2. In both the platform gcc compiles the program without errors. In MSYS2 (windows 10) I dont get the expected output, but in Linux I do get. Can you point out why?

I tried running similar program as follows in MSYS2 WINDOWS 10 host and Ubuntu VM.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int c;
   while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
       putchar(c);
   }
   putchar('\n');
   putchar(c);
   printf("\n Ended...\n");
}
```

"I expect the program to print whatever typed, whenever ENTER button is pressed. In Windows 10 there is no output printed even after pressing the enter button, but in Linux the output is printed properly and also the program is properly exited by pressing the EOF character which is Ctrl + D and the last output printed is Ended..."

Comment: Windows uses `Ctrl+Z` to generate the manual `EOF`, though you may have to enter it twice on its own line. I'll have to boot W10 to verify in MSYS2, but I suspect that is it.

Comment: Tried Ctrl+z,  but it forcibly ends the program, without printing anything.

Comment: #David could there be any other EOF for the MSYS2 console?

Comment: (c = getchar()) != EOF    you can instead EOF with 'a'.'1'....what you want exist on keyboard

Comment: IIRC windows doesn't line buffer standard output to a terminal. Add a `fflush(stdout);` after reading a newline and see if that helps.

Comment: And why do you write the EOF indication?

Comment: MSYS2 provides 3 compilers named `gcc`, so which one did you use?  You can run `which gcc` to see.  Also, what terminal and shell are you using?  The standard terminal for MSYS2 is MinTTY and the standard shell is Bash.

Comment: @DavidGrayson the gcc I am using is /mingw64/bin/gcc  the terminal I am using is  MSYS2 Mingw64 bit terminal which came with the setup.

Comment: I tried the same program with GCC installed in windows 10 using Cygwin64 and it is working as expected and as working in Linux.

Comment: @Shawn ```fflush``` workded it started printing. Thanks, cool. But I am not able to find the EOF for exiting it safely, I mean with the last line printed as "Ended...". Can you point out which key combination initiates the actual EOF operation.